# Using RAND with MD5 to generate unique key in MYSQL unique field. Possible? Acceptable practice?

Tags: php, mysql, random, md5, unique

I'm trying to implement a simple password reset system for my website. The idea is this:

1. User requests password reset link.
2. CodeIgniter system uses RAND and MD5 (I know it's unsecure and broken, probably best to use SHA1 or better, not the point) via MYSQL to generate a random string and hash it, producing 32bit key.
3. User is sent a link consisting of the key.
4. The rest is fairly obvious.

I want to find out if -

A: MYSQL functions RAND with MD5 (or better) being generated into a field set as UNIQUE, will automatically regenerate if they happen to generate a key that already exists in the table under that field.

B: This is an acceptable method to generate password reset links. Or is it better to hash the user's email address with a salt to prevent duplicates?

Obviously this is just the basic implementation and security needs wrapped around the whole process.

Comment: If you do something like this `md5(userID + random + time() + salt)` there should theoretically be no collisions (assuming userID) is the primary key.

Comment: A better system would use a large-ish salt string, the ID of the db record in question, and AES_ENCRYPT() + base64_encode(). It'll look randomish, but since it's AES encrypted, you can decrypt/extract it back to the original ID value if need be.

Comment: I agree, however, (and I know I'm being pedantic) but theoretically hasn't it been proven that MD5 can actually generate the same key for multiple inputs? So even if using your solution, we've given 4 unique values, is it not possible that it could generate a duplicate key?

My worry is really how MYSQL will handle it if in the one in a billion event that a duplicate is produced.

Comment: @MarcB Doing this would introduce a theoretical security breach. Using encryption means having to keep some key secret. If this key is leaked, your random strings could be forged.

Comment: @lukas: a breach of the db would leak the hashes anyways, so it's 6 of this, half a dozen of the other.

Comment: My first comment was for 1337holiday.

@Marc B, Thanks for the encryption suggestion :) however, for the first part of my question - how does MYSQL handle a duplicate situation when it has generated the duplicate and hasn't just been given it through an INSERT?

Comment: mysql can't do anything about a dupe until it's provided that dupe. e.g. an UPDATE or INSERT causes a "collision".

Comment: @MarcB The database does not need to be breach. Access to the web script - by exploiting a vulnerability or just accidently - would suffice to know the key (unless you use DB-side procedures).

Comment: @1337holiday: please tell me you are joking. Unless you have a proof by induction (which is impossible without knowing what the userids are) it is absurd to suppose, let alone assert that there will be no collisions.

Comment: breaching a script would by definition be a breach of the db anyways, since controlling a script would provide the same access to the DB as the script has, which would either be able to leak the key, or the hashes.

Comment: @MarcB This is a bit off-topic, but in terms of application security: Being able to **appear as the application** to the DB is something different from **knowing how the application works**. The latter one requires read access, the first one _execution_ privileges - at least when you limit the application's DB credentials to e.g. the web host.

Comment: It's trivial to add a transformation against the validation (token stored as x, f(a,x) sent to user, on submission, returned value tested against f(a,x)) which makes it effectively impossible to compromise the mechanism even if x, a and f() are known - in other words a read-only vulnerabilitiy does not compromise the integrity of the system (but someone with access to inject data or code can still compromise it).

Comment: @symcbean you must be a troll....did you miss the part where I SAID, it has to be a PRIMARY KEY? Or do you not understand the concept of a PK?

Comment: @1337holiday: No didn't miss that bit. If you can disprove the fundamentals of information theory, I can understand you're reticent to share your proof - this would make you richer than Bill Gates. But I still don't believe you have done so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much point in using a more sophisticated hash against simple, predictable values. Using the email as a salt helps - but not much. If you only need a random value then why not use a random value - dressing it up with pseudo-cryptography doesn't help the security (it actually undermines it here). Just generate a random number (actually, you probably want to generate several random numbers, convert to a more compact base and concatenate) and store it alongside the login information (you need to preserve the original password and unset the unlock if the user logs in successfully anyway).

Comment: I see your point but my point of using MD5 is not so much for encrypting the value, it's for creating a string as random as possible. Isn't MD5 good and suitable for this?

Comment: @dieselpower44 If you index your _password reset token_ column as `UNIQUE` and a duplicate occurs (which is **highly** unlikely to happen), the query will fail. Create a new random number, try again, and it's done.

Comment: Any hash contains less information than the data the hash was created from. Since the input to the hash here is much smaller than the output, there's also a large amount of redundancy being added here. Hashes do not add entropy to data. Again, if you want a random value, use a random value.

Comment: I see and this is the only option? Even if MYSQL itself created the collision using MD5(RAND)? It essentially takes MD5(RAND), does it once and if there's a collision - tough luck, try again?

Comment: Not using a random value is not the only option - but using a MD5 hash as you propose weakens is *significantly* weaker than using a random 128 bit value.

Comment: @dieselpower44 _Retry on duplicate_ is pretty much the fate of real _random_ values. But I, too, will tell you that not using a hash is better in terms of collision probability.

Comment: @symcbean Ahhh, sorry, I understand what you mean now. However, would you state the same if I proposed using a hashing algorithm that generated a 128bit value? Just curious.

Ignore this question - instead I ask, is it the general conclusion that using PHP to generate a random 128bit string is the best solution?

Comment: md5 *does* generate generate a 128 bit output

Comment: @dieselpower44 Using a hashing algorithm introduces some probability of generating a collision out of two different inputs. Also, this would be an absolutely **useless** step.

Comment: Sorry, it's late, I'm getting bits confused!

Comment: Answer provides solution to part B of my question, and this user along with several others have suggested determining uniqueness using PHP since MYSQL will NOT retry after failing (collision) with the asked functions.